# Enforcing Line Breaks \n In Objective C

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c

In Objective C I'm using the **loadHTMLString** to load a HTML string that has been inserted with a variable for JS. However, the string \n is not being included in the script.

For example, the code to be included:

`'Product:A\nProduct:B\nProduct:C'`

into java script as:

`var source = 'Product:A\nProduct:B\nProduct:C'`

However, in the completed HTML file the created script appears as:

`var source = 'Product:A Product:B Product:C '`

I need it to appear exactly as written for it to work. There are no substitutions:

`var source ='Product:A\nProduct:B\nProduct:C'`

Originally, I felt the problem was with formatting using: NSString stringWithFormat, but went with stringByAppendingString, but no luck - yet.

Thanks for your help

This is how the code appears when inserted by Obj C:

```
</head>
    <body>
        
        <h1>Absence Of Blood</h1>
        

        <canvas id="target-canvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('target-canvas')
            var source = 'Product:A 
Product:B 
Product:C 
'
            nomnoml.draw(canvas, source)
        </script>
        
    </body>
```

Obviously, it can only appear like this if code is entered in manually:

```
</head>
    <body>
        
        <h1>Absence Of Blood</h1>
        

        <canvas id="target-canvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('target-canvas')
            var source = 'Product:A\nProduct:B\nProduct:C'
            nomnoml.draw(canvas, source)
        </script>
        
    </body>
```

I think Objective C is formatting the \n into linefeed.

A simply fix could be replace \n with ^ in a var and use javascript function to read the code and replace the ^ with \n in var and feed it to:  `nomnoml.draw(canvas, modifiedSource)`

Or find a way to STOP Obj-C from converting \n into linefeeds.

A list of NSString options are here:

[NSStrings](https://eezytutorials.com/ios/nsstring-by-example.php#.Y3FjOC-B2j5)

but I didn't see anything that would make a difference.

Comment: `\n` is treated as a space in html. You have either change rendering to `pre` or replace `\n` with `<br>`

Comment: Hard to debug without seeing relevant code.

Comment: .......Can you show your objective-c code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want the literal text `\` and `n` to appear in the output. To do this you need to escape the `\n` in your Objective-C strings.

So instead of something like this:

```
NSString *output = @"var source = 'Product:A\nProduct:B\nProduct:C'";
```

you need to escape the backslashes:

```
NSString *output = @"var source = 'Product:A\\nProduct:B\\nProduct:C'";
```

This will put a literal backslash followed by the letter "n" in the result instead of interpreting the `\n` special escape sequence as a newline character.

Comment: Thanks - I was just thinking about trying that... cause I remembered when doing quotes, you need an extra one to bypass it!

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried it and it works:   \\n